# LINQ select: want to pass collection into CONTAINS

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, list

The page has 6 drop-down lists and a user can select a single item or leave the list on the first item which is 'ANY'.  In that case, I want to return all.  For instance, if the user chooses the SOIL drop-down ... the choices are ANY, Sand, Loam and Clay.  If they choose ANY,  I want to select all soil types from the SOIL table.  How could I pass a collection of soil types into a CONTAINS?  Something like:

```
*where soil.SOIL1.Contains("Sand", "Loam", "Clay")*

public List<PlantList> getMultiSelectPlantSearchResultBeSoMoLiHeZo(string Benefit, string Soil, string Moisture, string Light, string Height, string Zone)
{
    var plantList = from plant in db.PLANTs
                    join benefit in db.BENEFITs on plant.PLANT_ID equals benefit.PLANT_ID
                    join soil in db.SOILs on plant.PLANT_ID equals soil.PLANT_ID
                    join moisture in db.MOISTUREs on plant.PLANT_ID equals moisture.PLANT_ID
                    join light in db.LIGHTs on plant.PLANT_ID equals light.PLANT_ID
                    join height in db.HEIGHTs on plant.PLANT_ID equals height.PLANT_ID
                    join zone in db.ZONEs on plant.PLANT_ID equals zone.PLANT_ID
                    where plant.PLANT_ID == benefit.PLANT_ID
                    && benefit.BENEFIT1 == Benefit
                    && soil.SOIL1 == Soil
                    && moisture.MOISTURE1 == Moisture
                    && light.LIGHT1 == Light
                    && height.HEIGHT1 == Height
                    && zone.ZONE1 == Convert.ToInt16(Zone)
                    select new PlantList
                    {
                        plantId = plant.PLANT_ID,
                        plantName = plant.PL_NAME,
                        plantGenus = plant.PL_GENUS,
                        plantSpecies = plant.PL_SPECIES,
                        plantDesc = plant.PL_DESC,
                        plantImageThumb = plant.PL_IMAGE_THUMB,
                        plantBenefit = benefit.BENEFIT1,
                        plantSoil = soil.SOIL1,
                        plantMoisture = moisture.MOISTURE1,
                        plantLight = light.LIGHT1,
                        plantHeight = height.HEIGHT1,
                        plantZone = zone.ZONE1
                    };

    var DistinctItems = plantList.OrderBy(z => z.plantName).GroupBy(x => x.plantId).Select(y => y.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
    return DistinctItems;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use composability of `IQueryable`:

```
IQueryable<Soil> soils = db.SOILs;

if (soilTypes.Any())
{
    soils = soils.Where(s => soilTypes.Contains(s.Type));
}

var plantList = from plant in db.PLANTs
                join benefit in db.BENEFITs on plant.PLANT_ID equals benefit.PLANT_ID
                join soil in soils on plant.PLANT_ID equals soil.PLANT_ID
...
```

`soilTypes` contains the selection of types the user made (1 or more types as a list of strings). If the user chose "Any" it should just be an empty list (which effectively means that the selection criterion is ignored). So you should compose `soilTypes` based on what the user selected in the UI.

This will be translated into one SQL query, `soils` is an expression that is blended into the `plantlist` query.

Comment: Can you tell me, what is 'soilTypes' supposed to equate to?  There is no value 'soilTypes' in my SOIL entity.  The column in the DB is SOIL.SOIL1.

Comment: What type is `SOIL.SOIL1`?

Comment: SOIL1 is a string containing the values Sand, Loam, Clay from the drop-dlown list of SOIL TYPE.  It belongs to the SOIL table.  There is also a selection in the drop-down of ANY and if that is selected, I want to pull all soil types from the SOIL table.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ContainsAny method and call that on the where clause, see below a test example of that:

```
public static bool ContainsAny(string searchField, params string[] words) {
            foreach(string word in words) {
                if(searchField.Contains(word))
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }


        public static void Main(string[] args){
            var list = new List<string>() { "test", "test2", "Sand", "Loam", "Clay" };
            var selectedList = from item in list where ContainsAny(item, "Sand", "Loam", "Clay")
                               select item;
            foreach(var item in selectedList) {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```